# xamarin crossplatform canvas

Tags: c#, canvas, xamarin

I am investigating Xamarin as an option for our crossplatform solution. For us it is critical that we can create our own custom interactive controls.

The examples (http://devcenter.wintellect.com/jprosise/supercharging-xamarin-forms-with-custom-renderers-part-5) I've seen show how to create custom rendered controls. Unfortunately they all essentially show how to render to Canvas differently depending on platform. This is not acceptable for us.

Is there a true crossplatform way to create Xamarin custom rendered controls without writing same drawing logic in each platform specific implementation?

Answer (score 6):

I recently had to make the same decision and eventually I decided for SkiaSharp.

- SkiaSharp is a .NET binding to the Skia library and inherits the features and power of this library so in a way it's also possible to benefit of the original Skia documentation/examples/community
- SkiaSharp uses what actually powers Android and Chrome. Also, there is a hardware/GPU accelerated canvas and views.
- The only reason to prefer NGraphics it was the support for SVG but now from version 1.55 released on November 2016, SkiSharp support loading .svg files.
- Xamarin also published libraries for Xamarin.Forms and for Xamarin Android and iOS platform (SkiaSharp Views & Layers)
- Any Xamarin product has the support offered not just through Github but also Xamarin Website and Forum and Xamarin users community.
- With Xamarin there are better chance of the development and improvement of the library in the future.
- A single developer might have difficulties to improve or keep active the project for years.

Comment: Great points, but don't forget hardware acceleration via a OpenGL/DirectX context. Can be used in conjunction with a 3D render to draw on a 3D texture... Skybox's the limit! :)

Comment: @Matthew: True.

Comment: @Matthew, sorry for asking, do you have any suggestion on the following issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693821/rendering-svg-with-skiasharp-on-sksurfaceview-issue

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics

> NGraphics is a cross platform library for rendering vector graphics on .NET. It provides a unified API for both immediate and retained mode graphics using high quality native renderers.
>
> You can use it for cross platform rendering of UI widgets. Or as the basis for graphically rich interactive views. Or maybe you just want an easy way to import and export SVG and PNG files. Either way, I'm sure you'll find something interesting here.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative can be SkiaSharp which has more features than NControl/NGraphics

Read more at:
https://blog.xamarin.com/cross-platform-2d-graphics-with-skiasharp/

SkiaSharp is far superior to NGraphics in the sense that is uses what actually powers Android and Chrome. Also, there is a hardware/GPU accelerated canvas and views. Here is the source link: github.com/mono/SkiaSharp

Comment: I am the main guy working on SkiaSharp, so I am fairly biased. But, I do believe SkiaSharp is far superior to NGraphics in the sense that is uses what actually powers Android and Chrome. Also, there is a hardware/GPU accelerated canvas and views. Here is the source link: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp

Comment: I'll add that to ansver